# Resolve singleton generics where T is a controller that implements interface

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I have this situation:

```
public class MyController : Controller, ILoggable
{
     private readonly ILogger<ILoggable> _logger;

     public MyController(ILogger<ILoggable> logger)
     {
         this._logger = logger;
     }
     ...
}
```

I want to resolve `ILogger<ILoggable>` as singleton and `ILoggable` as Transient.
In my startup I tried with this:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(LoggerImpl<>));
```

But I am not able to resolve `ILoggable` because is a controller and I do not understand which is the best approach.

**EDIT**
Here is the problem:
I cannot declare `ILogger<MyController>` inside my controller because `ILogger<ILoggable>` is used in third part code. I try to explain better my problem without use dependency injiection.

I have a third part class that has a constructor like this>

```
Public ExternalClass(ILogger<ILoggable> logger) {…}
```

Now, in my controller I need to use this external class, but obviously I cannot do something like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller, ILoggable
{
     private readonly ILogger<MyController> _logger;

     public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger)
     {
         this._logger = logger;
         ExternalClass c = new ExternalClass(logger); //Here the error because logger is of type ILogger<MyController>, not ILogger<ILoggable>
     }
     ...
}
```

I need to solve that via DI.

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you

Comment: Why are you even trying to make your controller implement an interface? That doesn’t sound like a good idea, mostly because controllers usually aren’t registered with the DI container at all.

Comment: I also don’t understand why you think that `AddSingleton(typeof(IAnotherInterface<>), typeof(IAnotherInterface<>))` works. The second type argument is supposed to be the _implementation_. So it must be something that can be instantiated.

Comment: @poke, I have edited my question. I hope now it is clearer. However I actually think controllers are registered withthe DI container when I call `services.AddMvc()` in my `startup.cs`...

Comment: No, controllers are _constructed_ through the DI container but not automatically registered with it. You would have to use [`AddControllersAsServices()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvcbuilderextensions.addcontrollersasservices?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for that. That being said, I’m still not sure what exactly you want to do. Where do you want to resolve `ILoggable`? How is that registered, and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Just my controller implements ILoggable interface

Comment: Sure, but it can do that without being injected anywhere. So I am not sure what your problem is.

Comment: @poke I edited my post

Comment: If you need an `ILogger<ILoggable>`, then just inject that into your controller so that you can pass it on.